# Pass a global javascript variable into argument of an action form

Tags: javascript, forms, action

I would like to include a global javascript variable that it is dynamically updated into the argument of an action form.
Previously, I was simply using django template syntax to include the django variable string returned by the view into the action form but now that it is updated I need to come up with a way to pass this updated javascript variable into the GET method.
I save the variable as a window property "window.subgraph_query = 'foo'" this variable is supposed to change over time so it needs to be updated also in the form argument as well. How can I reach this? I think it should be easy

Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // BEFORE
    var subgraph_query = "{{ subgraph_query }}";

    //NOW
    window.subgraph_query = "{{ subgraph_query }}";

</script>

// BEFORE
<form action="/graph/network_to_gml/{{ subgraph_query }}" method="get">
   <input name="export-node-list" id="export-node-list"type="text"/>
</form>

// NOW

<form action="/graph/network_to_gml/JAVASCRIPT_VARIABLE" method="get">
   <input name="export-node-list" id="export-node-list"type="text"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use the onSubmit event or add a new (hidden) input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a hidden input field to your form and assign a value of a js variable. this way it won't be visible for a user but your script will receive it. 
Example of a hidden field type:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="country" id='hidden1' value="">
```

and in JS:

```
document.getElementById('hidden1').value = 'Poland';
```